# Is Bayes' theorem useless if $A$ is a subset of $B$?

Tags: bayes

Using Bayes' theorem, $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$

wouldn't this just be the percentage of $A$ in $B$ if $A$ is a subset of $B$?

If A is a subset of B:
$$P(B|A) = 1,$$
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$$

Therefore Bayes theorem becomes $\frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$ if $A$ is a subset of $B$.

So you don't really need to use Bayes' theorem in these situations, right?

Comment: I don't know how Macro deduced that James meant P(A|B)=1 if B⊂A rather than P(B|A)=1. Also James' equation P(A)/P(B)=A/B makes no sense and I really did not know what he meant. But Macro knew that he meant P(B|A) = P(B)/P(A) which is correct and would make sense that it is what James really meant.  Kudos to Macro!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bayes' Rule is still valid when $A \subset B$, but sometimes the conditional probabilities can be deduced intuitively in these situations. For example, it makes sense that if $A \subset B$, then $P(B|A) = 1$, since if $A$ happens, we know $B$ must have happened - you don't need Bayes Rule to see that. You are also right that in this case $P(A|B)=P(A)/P(B)$, which is just a special case of Bayes Rule, so I'd still say you "need" Bayes Rule in this case.

To make this more concrete, take an example: suppose you roll a fair die and $B$ is the event that the roll is even, while $A$ is the event the roll is a '6'. Clearly $A \subset B$. $P(B|A) = 1$, since if you rolled a '6', you clearly rolled an even number. Also

$$ P(A|B) = \frac{ P(B|A) \cdot P(A) }{ P(B) } = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{\frac{1}{6}}{ \frac{1}{2} } = \frac{1}{3} $$

This makes intuitive sense - conditioned on the fact that the roll is even, there are three equally likely outcomes - $\{2,4,6\}$ - therefore, the probability of rolling a '6' is $1/3$.

Comment: I don't see how the solution is different (aside from my meaning to say A is a subset of B). Your dice example is the same as the frequencies of A/B = 1/3.

I wrote P(A)/P(B) = A/B because you divide them both by the same number. In the dice example you would divide the frequencies both by 6 to get the probability.

Comment: @James, can you clarify what you mean by $A/B$? $A$ and $B$ are events, not numbers - what does their ratio mean?

Comment: I was responding to the apparent statement that Bayes' Theorem did not apply when one event was a subset of the other, and I've demonstrated that it still holds in that case. You don't *need* to use Bayes' rule in this case because the conditional probabilities are intuitively clear, but the theorem still holds nonetheless.

Comment: I mean frequencies. For example, say you have 1000 dogs. 100 of them are black, and 50 of those black dogs are mutts (all mutts are black). The probability of a dog being a mutt, given it is black, is A/B = 50/100 = 50%.

Comment: Ok that's what I thought.